# Не могу получить данные по API

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, iso8601

Ключи не рабочие. Просто ради примера привел.

```
import hmac
import base64
import requests
import json
import datetime

api_key = 'd024f2f3-2707-4504-8968-c25ddc7dd0dc',
secret_key = '6C2B92730CF43903CDC8C3986553FBC3',
passphras = 'Warlock2014'
timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%fZ")

CONTENT_TYPE = 'Content-Type'
OK_ACCESS_KEY = 'OK-ACCESS-KEY'
OK_ACCESS_SIGN = 'OK-ACCESS-SIGN'
OK_ACCESS_TIMESTAMP = 'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'
OK_ACCESS_PASSPHRASE = 'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'
APPLICATION_JSON = 'application/json'



def signature(timestamp, method, request_path, body, secret_key):
    if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
        body = ''
    message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(method) + request_path + str(body)
    mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
    d = mac.digest()
    return base64.b64encode(d)

# set request header
def get_header(api_key, sign, timestamp, passphrase):
    header = dict()
    header[CONTENT_TYPE] = APPLICATION_JSON
    header[OK_ACCESS_KEY] = api_key
    header[OK_ACCESS_SIGN] = sign
    header[OK_ACCESS_TIMESTAMP] = str(timestamp)
    header[OK_ACCESS_PASSPHRASE] = passphrase
    return header


def parse_params_to_str(params):
    url = '?'
    for key, value in params.items():
        url = url + str(key) + '=' + str(value) + '&'

    return url[0:-1]



base_url = 'https://www.okex.com'
request_path = '/api/account/v3/currencies'
# set request header
header = get_header('d024f2f3-2707-4504-8968-c25ddc7dd0dc', signature(timestamp, 'GET', request_path, body = '', secret_key= '6C2B92730CF43903CDC8C3986553FBC3'), timestamp, 'Warlock2014')
# do request
response = requests.get(base_url + request_path, headers=header)
# json
print(response.json())
```

Output:

```
{'error_message': 'Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP', 'code': 30005, 'error_code': '30005', 'message': 'Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'}
```

Пишет неверный timestamp. Сделал вроде как по их же требованиям.
Что не так делаю?

```
Unless otherwise specified, all timestamps from the API are returned in ISO 8601 with milliseconds resolution. Make sure you can parse the ISO 8601 format with the example below. Most modern languages and libraries can handle this without issues.

Example
2014-11-06T10:34:47.123Z
```

Библиотека на всякий случай. https://www.okex.com/docs/en/#summary-rules

Comment: Даже без запуска кода видно, что формат `%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%fZ` является неправильным — потеряли дефисы и двоеточия

Comment: Кст, тут запятые лишние: `api_key = 'd024f2f3-2707-4504-8968-c25ddc7dd0dc',` `secret_key = '6C2B92730CF43903CDC8C3986553FBC3',`. Такая запись это кортеж на 1 элемент, т.е. в `api_key` и `secret_key` не строки сейчас находятся, а кортежи. Запятые нужно убрать

Comment: Это жесть. Такой код лежит в библиотеке. Я подумал, можно доверить. Нет

Comment: Спасибо! Убрал, вы правы. Но проблема по-прежнему осталась. {'error_message': 'Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP', 'code': 30005, 'error_code': '30005', 'message': 'Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Руками сделал дату в нужном формате:

```
dt_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
ms = str(dt_now.microsecond).zfill(6)[:3]
timestamp = f'{dt_now:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S}.{ms}Z'
print(timestamp)
```

Пример:

```
2021-10-12T11:22:19.865Z
```

После этого уже другая ошибка:

```
{'error_message': 'Invalid Authority', 'code': 30012, 'error_code': '30012', 'message': 'Invalid Authority'}
```

Скорее всего, неправильное значение в `secret_key` или `passphras`

---

Весь код (немного его отрефакторил):

```
import base64
import datetime
import hmac

import requests


def signature(timestamp: str, method: str, request_path: str, secret_key: str, body: str = '') -> str:
    if not body:
        body = ''

    message = timestamp + method.upper() + request_path + body
    mac = hmac.new(
        bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf-8'),
        bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'),
        digestmod='sha256'
    )
    d = mac.digest()
    return base64.b64encode(d).decode('utf-8')


api_key = 'd024f2f3-2707-4504-8968-c25ddc7dd0dc'
secret_key = '6C2B92730CF43903CDC8C3986553FBC3'
passphras = 'Warlock2014'

dt_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
ms = str(dt_now.microsecond).zfill(6)[:3]
timestamp = f'{dt_now:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S}.{ms}Z'


base_url = 'https://www.okex.com'
request_path = '/api/v5/market/ticker'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'OK-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
    'OK-ACCESS-SIGN': signature(timestamp, 'GET', request_path, secret_key),
    'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
    'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': passphras,
}
params = {
    'instId': 'BTC-USD-SWAP'
}
# do request
response = requests.get(base_url + request_path, params=params, headers=headers)
# json
print(response.json())
```

Результат после изменения `request_path` и указания `instId`:

```
{'code': '0', 'msg': '', 'data': [{'instType': 'SWAP', 'instId': 'BTC-USD-SWAP', 'last': '56840', 'lastSz': '1', 'askPx': '56829', 'askSz': '347', 'bidPx': '56828.9', 'bidSz': '363', 'open24h': '56577', 'high24h': '57853.5', 'low24h': '56434.6', 'volCcy24h': '15309.4666', 'vol24h': '8759159', 'ts': '1634043284042', 'sodUtc0': '57491', 'sodUtc8': '57494.8'}]}
```

Comment: {'error_message': 'Please change to port v1 when you are using v1 apiKey. If you wish to use port v3, please register a v3 apiKey.', 'code': 30016, 'error_code': '30016', 'message': 'Please change to port v1 when you are using v1 apiKey. If you wish to use port v3, please register a v3 apiKey.'}

Comment: Попробую поискать v1 endpoints

Comment: Попробовал подставил v1 вместо v3. Ошибка декодирования. return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @Antony, выведите как `print(response.text)`, вангую что вам в `v1` вернулся `html` вместо `json`. И вам нужно понять api key какой версии API используется. Возможно, у вас реально api key для v1, тогда получить ключ для v3

Comment: Ответ - Forbidden =)))))

Comment: Скорее всего и статус http вернулся 403, а вообще Forbidden это https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403. Не знаю их api, но, возможно, способы авторизации/аутентификации у них разные

Comment: Да нет. Просто забили на информацию о том, что ключи версии v5. Нигде, ни слова. Ни одного.

Comment: @Antony, обновил в ответе ссылку с указанием `params`

Comment: Спасибо! Вы про!

Comment: @Antony, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно форматировать строку "вручную", есть же готовая функция [isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat), попробуйте её:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
# 2021-10-12T11:00:51.614611
```

Comment: Кст, пробовал запустить код автора с такой датой и ошибка такая же как у автора `Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP`, поискал и не нашел как честно сделать дату вида `2014-11-06T10:34:47.123Z`, поэтому в своем ответе сделал костыль :)

Comment: Именно так. Я до последнего пытался сам.

Comment: @gil9red Я такое предполагал, но странно, зачем там тогда пишут, что у них всё по `ISO` и нормальные ЯП в это умеют. Видимо, и правда дело в миллисекундах вместо микросекунд, была у меня такая версия, но проверять было лень.

Comment: {'error_message': 'Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP', 'code': 30005, 'error_code': '30005', 'message': 'Invalid OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'}

Comment: Вы знаете, я, конечно, не специалист Python, но у меня создается впечатление, что каждый уважающий себя финтех должен намудрить с timestamp. Но ни у кого не было одинакового варианта составления подписи.